# Valid website URL is required in Google Analytics

Tags: url, google-analytics, localhost, data-stream

I try to put the following URL to connect my web application to Google Analytics and it gives the error shown in the screenshot:

[image]

I tried changing the domain name and it didn't work either. If anyone has any idea how I can make it work, it would mean a lot! :)

Comment: You want to data stream from localhost?

Comment: Yes, because I have my project stored locally

Comment: try removing the ending slash.  if that doesn't work try using 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2):

You can use "localhost.local" or "example.com". The URL does not need to match the domain/URL you are actually using.

- for the host part of the URL there must be at least one "."
- ":" is not allowed left of the first "/"